# Using TableSort without doing a query

Tags: 8

Drupal core has the `Drupal\Core\Utility\TableSort` class which can be used to create tables with sortable columns. All examples in core however are based on `Drupal\Core\Database\Query\TableSortExtender` which providers table sorting for data coming from a database query.

I am looking to display data that is generated by custom code and is not originating from a query. How can I use the `TableSort` code directly in my controller?

This is the Drupal 8 version of the [same question for Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14889). See the answers there for additional insights.

Answer (score 6):

`TableSort` has methods to retrieve the sorting order and the field being sorted directly from the query arguments. You can use the values returned by `::getSort()` and `::getOrder()` to do a custom sorting of your data.

In your render array you can use some (undocumented) options in the `#header` declaration to control the way the table is initially sorted:

- `field`: the name to use in the query arguments to indicate that the table should be sorted by this column.
- `sort`: one (and only one) of the columns can be given this option (with value either `asc` or `desc`). This will be the column that is sorted by default.
- `initial_click_sort`: this can be set to `desc` if the data should be sorted in descending order if the column header is initially clicked. This defaults to `asc` but for some data you want to show larger numbers at the top by default.

Here is an example of a controller using data from a custom array:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Drupal\my_project\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Utility\TableSort;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

/**
 * Demo of a table with sortable columns using data from a custom source.
 */
class SortableTableDemoController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * The Symfony request stack.
   *
   * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack
   */
  protected $requestStack;

  /**
   * Constructs a new SortableTableDemoController.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack $requestStack
   *   The request stack.
   */
  public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack) {
    $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container): self {
    return new static(
      $container->get('request_stack')
    );
  }

  /**
   * Returns a render array containing data about Linux distributions.
   *
   * @return array
   *   The render array.
   */
  public function linuxDistributionsTable(): array {
    $headers = [
      // The distribution label has the 'sort' option, making it the default.
      [
        'data' => $this->t('Distribution'),
        'field' => 'label',
        'sort' => 'asc',
      ],
      [
        'data' => $this->t('Initial release'),
        'field' => 'year',
      ],
      // Sorted from highest to lowest on initial click.
      [
        'data' => $this->t('Packages'),
        'field' => 'packages',
        'initial_click_sort' => 'desc',
      ],
    ];

    $data = [
      ['label' => 'Arch Linux', 'year' => 2002, 'packages' => 77264],
      ['label' => 'Debian', 'year' => 1993, 'packages' => 118326],
      ['label' => 'Red Hat', 'year' => 2002, 'packages' => 12155],
      ['label' => 'Gentoo Linux', 'year' => 2002, 'packages' => 29092],
      ['label' => 'OpenSUSE', 'year' => 2006, 'packages' => 76236],
      ['label' => 'Ubuntu', 'year' => 2004, 'packages' => 89403],
    ];

    // Sort the table according to the options passed in the query arguments.
    $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    $sort = TableSort::getSort($headers, $request);
    $order_by = TableSort::getOrder($headers, $request)['sql'];

    usort($data, function (array $a, array $b) use ($sort, $order_by): int {
      $result = $a[$order_by] <=> $b[$order_by];
      return $sort === 'asc' ? $result : -$result;
    });

    return [
      'table' => [
        '#type' => 'table',
        '#header' => $headers,
        '#rows' => $data,
      ],
    ];
  }

}
```